# Codeigniter Image uploading not working on live server

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a situation where a user uploads his/her trip photos. They are saved in a folder and also supposed to be in database. Situation is: my code is working perfectly on localhost, and many other servers, but not on the server I want. Though it uploads files successfully, but the query is not executed which is supposed to save file path in database. I am stuck in this problem from more than a week. The same code works in other places. Here is my controller:

```
    public function trip_photos(){
    $this->load->model('UserModel');
    $this->load->model('CommentModel');
    $this->load->library('session');

    print_r($_FILES);

    $logged_session = $this->session->userdata('login');

    if($logged_session == 1) {
        $this->load->model('TripModel');
        $this->load->model('UserActivityModel');

        $uid = $this->session->userdata('uid');
        $tid = $this->input->post('tid');

        foreach($_FILES as $key => $image_upload){
            $upload = self::upload_trip_photo($key);
            if($upload['status']){
                $this->TripModel->add_trip_photo($uid, $tid, $upload['file']);
            }
        }
        $this->UserctivityModel->add_user_photo($uid, $tid);
    }else{
        redirect('/');
    }
}

private function upload_trip_photo($image){
    $msg = '';

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/trip/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 2048;
    $config['file_name'] = parent::getGUID();

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload($image))
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();

        $resize['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $resize['source_image'] = "./assets/images/trip/" . $data['file_name'];
        $resize['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $resize['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $resize['width']    = 222;
        $resize['thumb_marker'] = '';
        $resize['new_image'] = "./assets/images/trip/thumbnails/" . $data['file_name'];

        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($resize);

        if($this->image_lib->resize()){
            $status = true;
            $msg = $data['file_name'];
        }else{
            $status = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $status = false;
    }
    @unlink($_FILES[$image]);
    return array('status' => $status, 'file' => $msg);
}
```

when I enabled CI_Profiler, it says that only 2 out of 3 query executed on the server I want it to work. But the same profiler suggests that 3 of 3 queries executed on localhost or other servers. Its so confusing.
Please note that I already have checked the following:

1. File Upload: On
2. upload_raw_post_data: On
3. selinux permissions: disables (mine is centos)
4. File permissions: 777
5. php memory_limit: 128 MB
6. max_size: 8 MB
7. var_dump, print_r, echo all not working or displaying any information from controller.
   somehow, this in above code: `$upload = self::upload_trip_photo($key);` is not giving it back the file path it requires. Can anybody help please? @DFriend

**UPDATED** Turns out that in the localhost are other servers where its working, this array is returned by the function upload_trip_photo to the $upload variable:

```
Array ( [image0] => Array ( [name] => maintour3.jpg [type] => image/jpeg 
[tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php2539.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 200491 ) ) 
array(2) { ["status"]=> bool(true) ["file"]=> string(36) 
"E3965DFC8B265CEFF522A1EC43B33E34.jpg" }
```

while in the server where its not working, only this array is returned:

```
Array ( [image0] => Array ( [name] => mg7.jpg [type] => image/jpeg 
[tmp_name] => /tmp/phpNcCnX0 [error] => 0 [size] => 28460 ) )
```

It means this statement in the upload_trip_photo() function:
    return array('status' => $status, 'file' => $msg);

is not returning the requested array, with file name and status. And why? I am totally clueless.

Help Please!

Comment: images are uploading in specific folder or not ?

Comment: Hi @DeepParekh . Images are uploading in a specific folder, yes. The specific folder is root: /assets/images/trip/

Comment: ok thn jst the path or name of that image is not inserting in database right?

Comment: Exactly @DeepParekh the file with path name is not inserting. As I explained, CI_Profiler tells that insert() query is not even executed.

Comment: but in your code you are just upload an image you are not inserting in db in upload_trip_photo function.

Comment: @DeepParekh if you see the code above, this code fragment is calling a modal to send the query to database: ` foreach($_FILES as $key => $image_upload){
            $upload = self::upload_trip_photo($key);
            if($upload['status']){
                $this->TripModel->add_trip_photo($uid, $tid, $upload['file']);
            }
        }'

Comment: @DeepParekh I am inserting it, actually it goes to a model called TripModel, if you see closely in code. Controller is not supposed to work with database, only Models work with database. Moreover, the same code is saving it in the database.

Comment: @DeepParekh I have updated my question in the bottom. Can you please analyze it? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully this worked after extensive debugging. The line

```
if($this->image_lib->resize()){
        $status = true;
        $msg = $data['file_name'];
    }else{
        $status = false;
    }
```

was not working. Later when I set it to `display_error()` method, it showed that my server did not support GD library. This is an essential library to manipulate Graphics. So, the query was not being executed, as the $status variable was set to false.

I recompiled my php with GD Library module. And bigno! its working now.
Thanks for staying with me. :)